# Hibernate not updating postgres tables properly

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hibernate isn't updating my tables properly, and I can't figure out why. I have tried with Springboot version 3.3.0, 3.2.2, 3.1.8. PostgreSQL version 16, 15, 14 and 12. Java version 17 and 21. The example setup for showing the behavior can be seen in picture. [example setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN3vn.png)

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/randoset
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

Entity class:

```
package se.randoset.entity

import jakarta.persistence.Column
import jakarta.persistence.Entity
import jakarta.persistence.Id
import jakarta.persistence.Table
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import java.util.UUID

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class User(
    @Id
    var id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    @Column()
    var userName: String,
    var password: String
)

@Repository
interface UserRepository: JpaRepository<User, String>
```

When I start app and extract DDL from DBeaver, this is what it looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE public.users (
    id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "password" varchar(255) NULL,
    user_name varchar(255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

This is expected behavior.

If I then add a unique constraint on userName like so: `@Column(unique = true)` and restart app, the DDL is unchanged and no Hibernate log is shown. I expect Hibernate to add the constraint.

If I then change userName to userNameTest and again restart the app, I get these logs:

```
Hibernate: alter table if exists users add column user_name_test varchar(255)
Hibernate: alter table if exists users drop constraint if exists UK_kh8r0uhi4t5fb09nkdjjnopeg
Hibernate: alter table if exists users add constraint UK_kh8r0uhi4t5fb09nkdjjnopeg unique (user_name_test)
```

and now the DDL looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.users (
    id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "password" varchar(255) NULL,
    user_name varchar(255) NULL,
    user_name_test varchar(255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT uk_kh8r0uhi4t5fb09nkdjjnopeg UNIQUE (user_name_test),
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Here I expect Hibernate to change the variable's name, not create a new column, and also not add the constraint to the newly created column.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. It will only add new columns not modify existing ones. You shouldn't use hibernate to manage your schema instead you should be using something like Flyway or Liquibase.

Comment: Ah, I was sure it should alter them referring to previous experiences, guess I was wrong. So maybe just set ddl-auto to validate and use migration tool then?

Comment: That is what I generally do or forgo the validation and just maintain proper modification scripts.